# Is TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA still a secure cipher to use?

Tags: encryption, tls, rc4

I have read numerous times that the RC4 cipher itself is considered broken in TLS. Still many websites are using the *TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA* configuration even to date.

Now, I know that sometimes different uses of a cipher mitigate different attack scenarios, so my question is straightforward: Is this particular cipher configuration still considered secure, or are companies just not fast enough in changing to other configurations?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/853/google-is-using-rc4-but-isnt-rc4-considered-unsafe) and answers.

Comment: @mikeazo Thank you for pointing me there. I had kind of the same idea from reading around prior to asking, just wanted to make sure. I think it's sad that there is better cryptography available and usable, but not used because people are slow in switching.